# Manipulating Data frame with lists

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a dataframe of 55 rows x 556 columns witch each "case" of the matrix having a vector of six factors named: SMB,HML,UME.PROXY,RMW,CMA,MKT.NEW
As you can see in the following screenshot.

[image]

1) I need to average each Factor by column.

for example take all the values of the"UME.PROXY" coefficient of each vector in column one and average these values to end up with only one value (which is the average) for "UME.PROXY" for that column.

So at the end I would like to end up with a matrix lets call it matrix B
of 1 row x 55 columns with each column having a vector of 6 coefficients corresponding to the average of the column for each factor.

2) After that once I have that matrix I would eventually like to transform matrix B into matrix C to have 6 rows(one for each factor) per column (instead of a vector of 6 factors per column) so ending up with a Matrix C with 6 rows x 556 columns.

I hope it is clear and I would like to help you in advance for your help.

Here is the dput output:

```
dput(head(DF[10:10]))
structure(list(list(c(UME.PROXY = -1.46792406584093, SMB = -0.335928643143305, 
HML = 0.078951132459234, RMW = 0.0360759262269553, CMA = -0.147408484603944, 
MKT.New = 1.06013154345764), c(UME.PROXY = -1.47200056370772, 
SMB = -0.334924606368284, HML = 0.0315390552970403, RMW = -0.0486185515370473, 
CMA = -0.167573111918424, MKT.New = 1.05060486022485), c(UME.PROXY = -1.17480519297791, 
SMB = -0.224179562220809, HML = 0.0528513748129118, RMW = 0.0309448561191931, 
CMA = -0.182903201492864, MKT.New = 1.0573908044982), c(UME.PROXY = -1.49487748414678, 
SMB = -0.165851083093961, HML = 0.0499189826247655, RMW = 0.0407614788042679, 
CMA = -0.252505867514034, MKT.New = 0.984472836436174), c(UME.PROXY = -1.50422741241686, 
SMB = -0.174696974583352, HML = 0.0603046276438098, RMW = 0.0574529773429186, 
CMA = -0.255237723903091, MKT.New = 0.98208970318243), c(UME.PROXY = -1.50530479112584, 
SMB = -0.185226104674429, HML = 0.0215883125577546, RMW = 0.00313504487143439, 
CMA = -0.249274823685661, MKT.New = 0.98114333692362))), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can you use dput() on your data frame and post the result in  your question, rather than attaching pictures.

Comment: When using dput() I get a really long list of everything in my data frame I'm not sure its really clear to show? it looks like

 " c(UME.PROXY = -1.51798628773653, 
        SMB = 0.220258495786416, HML = -0.804956355493515, RMW = -1.31789747809505, 
        CMA = 0.222959621626054, MKT.New = 0.927845191207487)" over and over..

Comment: Share all the output of the `dput()` This will allow others to create your dataframe. It is not for humans to see, rather its for the computer to read in the data.

Comment: I managed to put the dput() using " dput(head(DF[10:10])) "

Comment: How committed are you to this way of structuring the data? It strikes me as terribly inconvenient, certainly for the task that you're interested in doing, and probably for most other tasks as well. If it were me, I'd strongly consider reshaping the data into a `data.frame` with one observation per row and columns something like: `UME.PROXY`, `SMB`, `HML`, `RMW`, `CMA`, `MKT.NEW`, `old_row`, `old_col` (where these last two track what the row / column numbers used to be in the data.frame in your picture / dput).